# Using generics in es6 Map with Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, ecmascript-6

I've got a project in Typescript 2.0 and I'm using `es6` as my module, with the lib `es2017` included so I can use maps. I've got everything working except I seem to need to do some unnecessary casts.

```
static readonly gameStateMap: Map<GameState, Phaser.State> = new Map([
    [GameState.PONG, new PongState() as Phaser.State],
    [GameState.BREAKOUT, new BreakoutState() as Phaser.State]
]);
```

Why do I need to cast them to `Phaser.State`? Since they both directly extend `Phaser.State` I thought I should be able to just stick them in the map with no problem.

I thought maybe I just needed to refine my generics declaration, so I tried:

`Map<GameState, V extends Phaser.State>`.

I see that syntax used in [Typescript's generics docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

But it doesn't work. Is this an ES6 generic and that's my problem? How can I fix this to not need to cast?

Also, this issue only occurs if the classes in question have different properties. The error is:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '((GameState | PongState)[] | (GameState | BreakoutState)[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<[GameState, State]>'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something wrong if your system. You need to provide more info.

It is working in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20GameState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PONG%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BREAKOUT%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20Phaser%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20State%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PongState%20implements%20Phaser.State%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20BreakoutState%20implements%20Phaser.State%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20gameStateMap%3A%20Map%3CGameState%2C%20Phaser.State%3E%20%3D%20new%20Map(%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BGameState.PONG%2C%20new%20PongState()%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BGameState.BREAKOUT%2C%20new%20BreakoutState()%5D%0D%0A%5D)%3B%0D%0A)

```
enum GameState {
    PONG,
    BREAKOUT
}

namespace Phaser {
    export interface State { }
}

class PongState implements Phaser.State { }
class BreakoutState implements Phaser.State { }


let gameStateMap: Map<GameState, Phaser.State> = new Map([
    [GameState.PONG, new PongState()],
    [GameState.BREAKOUT, new BreakoutState()]
]);
```

UPDATE:
The issue you face is that you declare type manually and rely on inferring. The inferring can only do so much. In this case, the two inner array can't be inferred to a common type, thus they ended up as `[{}, {}]`.
The solution is to use the generic directly:

```
enum GameState {
    PONG,
    BREAKOUT
}

namespace Phaser {
    export interface State { }
}

class PongState implements Phaser.State { a: string }
class BreakoutState implements Phaser.State { b: string }


let gameStateMap = new Map<GameState, Phaser.State>([
    [GameState.PONG, new PongState()],
    [GameState.BREAKOUT, new BreakoutState()]
]);
```

Comment: I played around with your playground to make it more closely resemble my code, and was able to recreate the issue by changing the class declarations to this: `class PongState implements Phaser.State { stuff: string; }` `class BreakoutState implements Phaser.State { notStuff: number; }`. It seems the issue only occurs if the classes contain different properties.

Answer (score 1):

When you write it in this way

```
let gameStateMap: Map<GameState, Phaser.State> = new Map(...)
```

compiler first tries to infer a type for `new Map`, then checks if it's compatible with the type declared for `gameStateMap`.

In your case, when arrays with elements having different types are involved, compiler fails to infer common type for them and uses union type instead (the intended type for `Map` argument apparently is `[GameState, Phaser.State][]` ).

Compiler needs a little help with this, you can provide it by giving explicit generic arguments to `Map` constructor, and then you can omit explicit type declaration for `gameStateMap`:

```
enum GameState { PONG, BREAKOUT };
namespace Phaser {
    export interface State { }
}

class PongState implements Phaser.State { a: string }
class BreakoutState implements Phaser.State { b: string}

let gameStateMap = new Map< GameState, Phaser.State > ([
    [GameState.PONG, new PongState()],
    [GameState.BREAKOUT, new BreakoutState()]
]);
```